# How do you save, or make check points using the blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine

So recently I’ve tried using some the game engine side of blender as opposed to the animation work I usually do, I’m enjoying using it and have learnt the basics of how to make an operational game, but I’ve got no idea how to make a save/load point for my game.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

==> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ErvI2CB8UUhBa_-L1dVRnI_3jPoX93rF   <==

above is simple system example of save 'n load system (saves to text in your computer).
it's pretty simple when near sensor is triggered it's automatically saving if you want it to be manual add keyboard sensor and if you want to make limited amount of saves, add an property sensor(which decrease with each save) and so on and so forth . logic is pretty basic . Feel free to study and use the example blend file.